# Unity Cardboard Export in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I exported the Unity Cardboard project to an Android Project and imported it into my Android Studio. I can compile the project and run it in my  Smartphone through Android studio. Now, I have been working in an Android App that reads some QR codes and load an Scene of Unity but I can't choose the scene in my Android Activity, I just have an Intent to .

How can I load a specific Scene in my own Activity in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the best place for you to find good Unity-related answers is in answer.unity3d.com.

Have you tried on this?
[Android/Unity - Launching activity from unity activity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/780406/androidunity-launching-activity-from-unity-activit.html)

Another clean solution is try to find the barcode scanner/generator in Unity Asset Store. Might to pay a little for it but could save you some time.